# Install hadoop-2.6.0 in ubuntu 14.0

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, hadoop2

How to *install Hadoop-2.6.0* in *Ubuntu 14.0* ?
Please anyone tell installation procedure

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Comment: You can refer [this article](http://dasunhegoda.com/hadoop-2-deployment-installation-ubuntu/1085/) which explains how to configure Hadoop 2 in a clustered environment. All the necessary steps are mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop Pseudo node Installation

Prerequisites:

```
 1.Installing Java v1.8 
 2.Creating dedicated Hadoop system user. 
 3.Configuring SSH access. 
 4.Disabling Ipv6.
```

1) `Installing Java:` 
Hadoop is a framework written in Java for running applications on large clusters of commodity 
hardware. Hadoop needs Java 6 or above to work.

Step 1: Download jdk tar.gz file for linux-64 bit, extract it into “/usr/local”

```
root@localhost  cd /usr/local
root@localhost  tar xvzf /boss/Downloads/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
root@localhost  cd /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_05
```

Step 2:

Open the `“/etc/profile”` file and Add the following line as per the version 
set a environment for Java 
Use the root user to save the /etc/profile. 
The 'profile' file contains commands that ought to be run for login shells

```
root@localhost sudo vi /etc/profile
```

## --insert JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME= /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_05
```

## --in PATH variable just append at the end of the line

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

## --Append JAVA_HOME at end of the export statement

```
export PATH JAVA_HOME
```

Step 3:   Source the /etc/profile

```
root@localhost source /etc/profile (or) sudo . /etc/profile
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 4:    Update the java alternatives

By default OS will have a open jdk. Check by “java -version”. You will be prompt “openJDK”
If you also have openjdk installed then you'll need to update the java alternatives:

If your system has more than one version of Java, configure which one your system causes by entering
  the following command in a terminal window

By default OS will have a open jdk. Check by “java -version”. You will be prompt “Java HotSpot(TM) 64-
  Bit Server”

```
root@localhost   update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" java "/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" = 1



 root@localhost update-alternatives --config java
```

--type selection number:

```
 root@localhost  java -version
```

2) Disable IPV6:

Apache Hadoop is not currently supported on IPV6 networks. It has only been tested

and developed on IPV4 stacks. Hadoop nees only IPV4 to work and allows only IPV4

clients to communicate with the cluster.

Now we are going to disable the IPV6 entry in “sysctl.conf”

We need to edit sysctl.conf in the etc folder, open

```
 root@localhost vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the following lines at end of the file

## disable ipv6

```
 net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

 net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

3) Create User for Hadoop

Step 1: Now going to create user called “hdfs” & group called “hadoop”.

```
root@localhost adduser hdfs
```

--set password for user “hdfs”, for simplicity use password also “hdfs”

```
 root@localhost  addgroup hadoop
```

-- Check the user and group id

```
 root@localhost  adduser hdfs hadoop
```

Step 2: Once user is created

## id hdfs

## setfacl -m u:hdfs:rwx /opt

Step 3 : make sure all the Hadoop installation should be done under “hdfs”.

```
root@localhost # su hdfs
```

3) SSH Configuration: (OPTIONAL but painful if u omit this)

Hadoop requires SSH access to manage its nodes, i.e. remote machines plus

your local machine if you want to use Hadoop on it (which is what we want to

do in this short tutorial). For our single-node setup of Hadoop, we therefore

need to configure SSH access to localhost

The need to create a Password-less SSH Key generation based authentication

is so that the master node can then login to slave nodes (and the secondary

node) to start/stop them easily without any delays for authentication This has

to be setup on the secondary namenode.

If you skip this step, then have to provide password for all slave when Master

start the process by ./start-*.sh. If you have configured more no.of slave as

mentioned in /etc/hosts, repeat the 2nd line of above to all the slaves by

slave1, slave2 etc.

Generate an SSH key for the user. Then Enable password-less SSH access to

```
         your local machine with this newly created key.
```

--You will be asked to enter password,

```
 hdfs@localhost # ssh localhost
```

-- press ctrl c

```
hdfs@localhost# ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa

hdfs@localhost# ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost
```

--After above 2 steps, You will be connected without password,

```
hdfs@localhost# ssh localhost

hdfs@localhost# exit
```

4) Hadoop Installation:

Now Download Hadoop from the official Apache, preferably a stable
  release version of Hadoop 2.6.0 and extract the contents of the Hadoop package to a location of              your choice.

We chose location as “/opt/”

Step 1: Download the tar.gz file of latest version Hadoop ( hadoop-2.6.0 ) from the official site .

Step 2: Extract(untar) the downloaded file from this commands to /opt/hdfs

```
 hdfs@localhost# cd /opt/

 hdfs@localhost# sudo tar -vxzf hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz

 hdfs@localhost# cd hadoop-2.6.0
```

Step 3: Creating the environment through ~/.bashrc file

“bashrc” file uses a collection of startup files to help create an environment. Each file has

a specific use and may affect login and interactive environments differently. The file in

the $HADOOP_HOME/bin directory generally provide global settings throughout the

whole shell

```
 hdfs@localhost# vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines at end of the file

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_05

 export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-2.6.0

 export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME

 export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

 export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

 export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

 export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

 export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

 export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

 export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 4: Source the ~/.bashrc

```
 hdfs@localhost# source ~/.bashrc
```

Step 5: Modify hadoop environmental files:

Hadoop

```
 environmental files placed under “/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/” i.e

  $HADOOP_HOME


  Add JAVA_HOME to “libexec/hadoop-config.sh”.


 hdfs@localhost# cd /opt/hadoop-2.6.0

 hdfs@localhost# vi libexec/hadoop-config.sh
```

Add “JAVA_HOME”

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_25
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 6:

Add JAVA_HOME to etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh. Under /opt/hadoop-2.6.0

```
 hdfs@localhost# vi etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

Add “JAVA_HOME”

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_25
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 7: Check Hadoop Installation

```
 hdfs@localhost# cd /opt/hadoop-2.6.0

 hdfs@localhost# bin/hadoop version
```

At this point Hadoop installed in your node.

4.1) Create a folder called tmp

TMP will be used as a base for other temporary directories ( for name-node and
 data-node ) locally and also in HDFS. The reason for creating a tmp folder is to move all the files to a secure location away from all the other standard hadoop
 files.

```
 hdfs@localhost# mkdir -p /opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/datanode

 hdfs@localhost# mkdir -p /opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/namenode
```

4.2) Modify the Hadoop Configuration Files

In this section, we will configure the directory where Hadoop will store its

configuration files, the network ports it listens to, etc. Our setup will use Hadoop

Distributed File System,(HDFS), even though we are using only a single local

machine.

Add the following properties in the various hadoop configuration files which is available
  under  $HADOOP_CONF_DIR   which  is   usually in  the

```
 $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
```

core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml & yarn-site.xml

Step 1: Modify core-site.xml

```
 hdfs@localhost# cd /opt/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop

 hdfs@localhost# vi core-site.xml
```

Paste following between  tags

```
 <property>

 <name>fs.default.name</name>

 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>

 </property>

 <property>

 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>

 <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp</value>

 </property>
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 2: Modify hdfs-site.xml

```
 hdfs@localhost# vi hdfs-site.xml
```

Paste following between  tag

(configure the path for the namenode and datanode )

```
 <property>

 <name>dfs.replication</name>

 <value>1</value>

 </property>

 <property>

 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>

 <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/namenode</value>
```

```
 <property>

 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>

 <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/datanode</value>

 </property>
```

Note: Here I've only one node so we’ve put the replication value as 1. In multi-node setup you’ll

have to increment the replication value based on the number of slave-nodes you have.

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 3: Modify mapred-site.xml

Rename the existing mapred template to mapred-site.xml

```
 hdfs@localhost# cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml

 hdfs@localhost# vi mapred-site.xml
```

Paste following between  tag

```
 <property>

 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>

 <value>yarn</value>

 </property>
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Step 4: Modify yarn-site.xml

```
 root@localhost# vi yarn-site.xml
```

Paste following between  tags

```
 <property>

 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>

 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>

 </property>
```

---

```
 <property>

 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>

 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
```

```
 <property>

 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>

 <value>localhost:8025</value>

 </property>
```

---

```
 <property>

 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>

 <value>localhost:8030</value>
```

```
 <property>

 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>

 <value>localhost:8050</value>

 </property>
```

save the file using by pressing “Esc” key followed by :wq!

Formatting the HDFS file-system via the NameNode

The first step to starting up your Hadoop installation is formatting the Hadoop files

system which is implemented on top of the local file system of our “cluster” which

includes only our local machine. We need to do this the first time you set up a Hadoop

cluster.

Do not format a running Hadoop file system as you will lose all the data currently in

the cluster (in HDFS)

To format the namenode (which simply initializes the directory specified by the

dfs.name.dir variable), run the following commands:

```
 hdfs@localhost# cd $HADOOP_HOME

 hdfs@localhost# bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Starting a Hadoop Cluster

Issue the command following command to start HDFS: ( To start namenode and datanode)

```
 hdfs@localhost# sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

To check what services have started type in the jps command in our JAVA_HOME

```
 hdfs@localhost# jps (or) /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/jps
```

## Output:

```
 21422 Jps

 21154 DataNode

 21070 NameNode

 21322 SecondaryNameNode
```

To start YARN:

To start resource manager and node manager

```
 hdfs@localhost# sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

To check what services have started type in the jps command in our JAVA_HOME

```
 hdfs@localhost# jps (or) /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/jps
```

## Output:

```
 21563 NodeManager

 21888 Jps

 21154 DataNode

 21070 NameNode

 21322 SecondaryNameNode

 21475 ResourceManager
```

Stopping of Hadoop Cluster:

To stop the Hadoop cluster and associated service use the following command.

To stop DFS services

```
 hdfs@localhost# sbin/stop-yarn.sh
```

To stop YARN services

```
 hdfs@localhost# sbin/stop-dfs.sh
```

–-----------------------------------------THE END----------------------------